# What's the correct data type?

Tags: c

I'm learning to program embedded ethernet and I'm having a problem with a piece of code:

```
uint8   emacAddress[6U] =   {0x00U, 0x08U, 0xEEU, 0x03U, 0xA6U, 0x6CU};
uint32  emacPhyAddress  =   0U;

int main(void)
{

hdkif_t hdkif01;
hdkif01.mac_addr[6] = emacAddress;
```

When I build the code, I get two warnings about the last line:

1. 515-D a value of type "uint8 *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint8_t"
2. 177-D subscript out of range

The "hdkif_t" is defined as:

```
typedef struct hdkif_struct {
  /* MAC Address of the Module. */  
  uint8_t mac_addr[6];

  /* emac base address */
  uint32 emac_base;

  /* emac controller base address */
  volatile uint32 emac_ctrl_base;
  volatile uint32 emac_ctrl_ram;

  /* mdio base address */
  volatile uint32 mdio_base;

  /* phy parameters for this instance - for future use */
  uint32 phy_addr;
  boolean (*phy_autoneg)(uint32 param1, uint32 param2, uint16 param3);
  boolean (*phy_partnerability)(uint32 param4, uint32 param5, uint16* param6);

  /* The tx/rx channels for the interface */
  txch_t txchptr;
  rxch_t rxchptr;
  }hdkif_t;
```

What is the correct data type of emacAddress and why?

Comment: Why are postfixing the constants with `U` everywhere?  You really don't need it in your presented code *at all*.

Comment: This issue is not with the datatype but with your syntax.

Comment: That is simply not how you copy an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `hdkif01.mac_addr[6] = emacAddress;` is assigning the pointer to the array `emacAddress` to the *seventh* element  of `hdkif01.mac_addr`. Remember that array indices are zero-based in C.

Since `hdkif01.mac_addr` is an array of `uint8_t`, the seventh element (A) does not exist, and (B) is not large enough to hold a pointer. (B) is the reason for your error.

It looks like you are trying to copy an array. You have some options, listed from most manual to least:

1. Copy element-by-element with no loop:

   ```
   hdkif01.mac_addr[0] = emacAddress[0];
   hdkif01.mac_addr[1] = emacAddress[1];
   ...
   hdkif01.mac_addr[5] = emacAddress[5];
   ```
2. Copy element-by-element in a loop:

   ```
   int i;
   ...
   for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       hdkif01.mac_addr[i] = emacAddress[i];
   ```
3. Use a function:

   ```
   #include <string.h>
   ...
   memcpy(hdkif01.mac_addr, emacAddress, sizeof(emacAddress));
   ```